# VS2013 Immediate Window runs application, does not evaluate

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

This is my problem, when i run code from a WPF application using the immediate window, instead of evaluating the code, it runs the whole application. This only happens with VS2013, in VS2012 (i have both installed) this does not happen.

The strange part here is that when i create a regular Winforms application or even a dll and evaluate the same code, the immediate window evaluates it normally.

Here is an error i get if i try to evaluate the code multiple times after the WPF app runs: "An expression evaluation is already in progress."

But it never does evaluate in WPF apps.

Here is the code i used to test this behavior:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
public class W
{
    public static int[] T()
    {
        return new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    }
}
```

The output for winforms or dll is this (as expected):

WindowsFormsApplication1.W.T()
 {int[5]}
     [0]: 1
     [1]: 2
     [2]: 3
     [3]: 4
     [4]: 5

For wpf: nothing, just runs the app...

Is this an intended feature or a bug? Do other people have this or is it just me?

Comment: No repro on a stock do-nothing WPF app.  It all rather depends on exactly where you put that class and what static constructors you have in your code, details you should not leave out of the question.  Hard to imagine why doing this is useful.

Comment: @HansPassant It doesn't seem to matter where i put that class, it always does the same thing. But my issue is that if i try the same code and same layout in vs2012 it works as expected. I am thinking this is a vs2013 issue/feature. And it is useful for me at least to use the immediate window to evaluate some code and quickly see the output without having to debug or make a unit test.